# How to remove files inside the hadoop directory at once?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to remove all the files containes in hadoop directory, without removing the directory itself. I've tried using `rm -r`
but it removed the whole directory.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please include a wildcard character `*` after the desired folder you want to delete, to avoid deleting the parent folder. Please look at the example below:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r '/home/user/folder/*'
```

Comment: `hdfs` is deprecated - use `hadoop fs -rm -r /path/to/folder/*` instead. Also you can use `-f` option to delete file forcefully

Comment: @BigDataLearner It seems that you don't need `-f` the deletion is already forcefull with `hadoop fs -rm -r`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I trusted you and didn't use the flag `-f` as you said, but it moved all my files to the trash ! So you should use the `-f` flag if you don't want to `hdfs dfs -expunge`. I used the command : `hdfs dfs -rm -r ${HDFS_BASEDIR}/myrepo/*`

Comment: @bobolafrite the `-f` flag is normally to indicate that you also want to delete a folder if it contains files. (so f stands for forcefully, which here is not needed). If you want to avoid moving things to the trash (which was not mentioned in the question) then it is best to use the '-skipTrash' flag.

Comment: @RonakPatel, hdfs command is still used in hadoop 3.x so it's safe to use hdfs dfs -rm ... command

Answer (score 5):

referring to the previous answer, you need to quote the asterisk:
    `hdfs dfs -rm -r "/home/user/folder/*"`

Answer (score 1):

Use hdfs command to delete all files in it. For example, if your hadoop path is `/user/your_user_name/*` then use asterisk to delete all files inside the specific folder.

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r '/user/your_user_name/*'
```